# How to draw a FSA on a canvas legibly?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I'm developing a small application using joint.js that displays a Finite State Automata. My problem is that once it gets so large, the diagram becomes a mess of wires and is hard to read. I need to draw it in such a way that the user can clearly see what is going on without much manipulation on their part.

It has a start state and an end state, so I put those on the top and bottom of the canvas respectively. But I have a good amount of room on it.

What sort of algorithms to arrange the state locations are available, and how do they work?

Comment: could you post a picture, so we can understand 'is hard to read' ?

Comment: A finite state automata is essentially a directed graph. Take a look at springy.js, a force directed graph layout algorithm in JavaScript: http://getspringy.com/

Comment: @AaditMShah +1 Nice suggestion with the springy.js tool.  d3 is also a good tool for creating force graphs if the project permits SVG: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045. I'm not sure I exactly agree that FSM ~= forceDirectedGraph.  IMHO, a large number of many-to-many relationships plus recursions that exist in real-world often make FSM !~= FDGraph. Anyway, cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncluttered distribution of your states and connectors might not be possible.

That all depends on how much reflection and recursion occurs through your states.

In general, if you schema lends itself to being linear, lay out the states linearly from left to right (or visa-versa) because that's the way the eye likes to visualize change.

In general, if your schema is highly reflective/recursive, lay out the states in a hub-spoke with often active states at the center hub and less active states at the outside spokes.

But again, real life is messy.  It's possible that neither of these generalizations are applicable to your data.

**However...**

You can use the dynamic ability of html canvas to lessen the distraction of your connectors.

At the starting state, make every connector less noticable:

- Draw all connections at 25% opacity (context.globalAlpha=.25)
- Draw the connections thin (maybe context.lineWidth=1 or even 0.5)

When any connection is activated during a transition, make it highly noticeable.

- Bring that connection to 100% opacity
- Make that connection thick (maybe lineWidth=3.00)

After a connection is activated, slowly animate its properties from its highly noticeable visibility to less noticeable (html canvas is very good at animating)

- Animate that connector back to 25% opacity
- Animate that connector back to 1.0 lineWidth

If you don't need all your states to be readily visible at all times, you could apply the same kind of visual queues to states as well as connectors.

*Hint: Don't forget color!*

The user more easily mentally connects 2 states if they are temporarily the same color.  This lessens the need for a bold connector between the states.

*Hint: Give the user clues!*

The mind quickly picks up on clues.  For example, when 2 states activate, if the originating state is surrounded by 1 circle and the destination state is surrounded by 2 circles, the user will quickly pick up on that pattern and mentally connect those 2 states.  This lessens the need for a bold connector between the states.

**And...**

A user will understand your process more quickly/thoroughly if they can be in control of your state machine.

You could use a slider to let the user move from the starting to ending state conditions at their own pace.  They can "replay" the parts to reinforce their understanding.

Good luck with your project--it sounds interesting!

Comment: reducing the line's width below one has an effect very similar to reducing opacity, so playing on this factor alone is worth a try in a first pass at least.